# Locked iPhone showing music controls when website has youtube iframe

Tags: iphone, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have a youtube video embedded onto a website. When a user locks their iPhone, the music controls are displayed on the locked screen. The controls are displayed even if the youtube vidoes are not being played.

Is there any way to stop the music controls from being displayed?